# Is there a better way of handling this list of strings?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am developing an app for **Android**

I have different categories:

```
String[] cat = { "Category",  "Books", "Clothing", "Shoes", "Hobbies", 
                 "General", "Electronics", "Transportation", "Medicine",
                 "Sports", "Education", "Outdoor"};
```

The UI asks the user to select a category, Name, and some description which is then written to a db. When the user presses the List button, every category that is filled is shown and the items under that category is also show using an **ExpandableListActivity**.

```
List<List<String>> children = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

/**********************
  I have a list for each category!!! But I don't like this solution. :(
**********************/
List<String> books = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> clothing = new ArrayList<String>();
    ...
    ...

public void fillData() {

// Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchAllItems();

startManagingCursor(c);

// for all rows
for(int i=0; i<c.getCount(); i++)
{
    // next row
    c.moveToNext();

    // pick a category
    String t = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("category"));

    switch (getCat(t))
    {
    case Books:
        books.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
        break;
    case Clothing:
            // do stuff for Clothing
        break;

     /**
       And there are other cases for the rest of the categories but i am not listing
       them here, since it is the same process
     */
        default:
        break;
    }   // end switch
} // end for loop

    //for each category that has been filled up
    children.add(category);
} // end function
```

**My Question:**

is it possible to not have to create a list for each category? I tried with one list but the results do not look very good. All categories show the same items and not the individual items, which makes sense.

Comment: Don't really think so. A list of lists seems to be the best way to structure your data without getting overly complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just created a list of lists, and worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create the lists yourself.

You may want to have 2 tables - one listing the categories names and their ids (which will be primary table key) another one listing the stuff where each row has an item's category id, an item name and whatever else for a single item.

Then you can have `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` like this:

```
SimpleCursorTreeAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor, int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo).
```

For `groupLayout` you will have `android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1`. For `childLayout` you will have `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

For `groupFrom` you will have

String[] groupFrom = { FLD_CATEGORY_NAME };
 int[] groupTo = { android.R.id.text1 };

For childFrom you will have

```
String[] childFrom = { FLD_ITEM_NAME };
int[] childTo = { android.R.id.text1 };
```

or rather your own layout if you want to display more than 1 or 2 elements

And you will have

```
protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
      int categoryId = groupCursor.getColumnIndex(FLD_CATEGORY_ID);
      // and here you a Cursor from your items table WHERE CTAEGORY_ID == categoryId
}
```

Comment: but wouldn't it be a little messy if say the user wants to delete an item. eg under books i want to delete 'perl programming'?

Comment: @rashid I just meant SimpleCursorTreeAdapter is good to display table data in an ExpandableListView